# My graphic card overloads when i use flash player

Tags: ati, graphics, flash

When I just use my laptop normally everything works just fine.

But as soon as I watch a youtube video or anything else that uses flash player in firefox my laptop starts to sound very loud. I have checked my CPU performance when this happens and my CPU is not at more then 10-20% (intel i5 quad). As soon as I pause or close youtube/flash my laptop isnt so loud anymore.

I figured this might have to do with the graphic card and I wanted to know if there is any tests I can run to see how my graphic card is behaving when I'm using flash player. 
When I run System testing I get this:

```
OpenGL vendor string: ATI Technologies Inc. OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon HD 6400M Series OpenGL version string: 4.2.12337 Compatibility Profile Context 13.101 Not software rendered: yes Not blacklisted: yes GLX fbconfig: yes GLX texture from pixmap: yes GL npot or rect textures: yes Compiz supported: yes
```

Because I use flash player a lot I'm quite concerned about how my laptop is behaving. I run ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

How to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I more or less ran into the same issues on an old (outdated) PC*: CPU started to work really hard and Youtube videos became choppy when played at fullscreen - HD videos even in a small screen. I eventually discovered that copy-pasting the URL from a Youtube video into VLC Player (use CTRL-N, then paste), virtually eliminated all choppiness and gave me smooth fullscreen videos. Not a perfect solution, but might be an acceptable work-around for some.. Btw DVD-video is also normal when I play it in VLC-player.

As a side-note, I also noticed that most videos played smoother on the Youtube site when I was using a Ubuntu live-USB (although I did get pop-ups about flash not being installed just before the video started playing).

*Pentium IV 2,8 GHz, about 1,7 Gb of ram, HP Compaq D330, Graphics card: Ati radeon 9200PRO - so I suppose it could be a mix of old hardware, bad drivers and imperfect browser-plugins. Btw I experienced the same issue in a whole bunch of Ubuntu flavours and Mint, but Lubuntu still performed best (because of the low system load).